# jasypt digest implementation in PHP

Tags: php, scala, jasypt

We have an application in Scala which uses `org.jasypt.digest.PooledStringDigester` for manipulation passwords. In our code we have something like this:

```
private val digester = new PooledStringDigester()
digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256")
digester.setIterations(100000)
digester.setSaltSizeBytes(16)
digester.setPoolSize(200)
digester.initialize()
```

and we digest our passwords with `digester.digest(password)`. We have to do something similar in PHP, but couldn't figure any way to generate a similar hash like this Scala library. Is there any implementation of jasypt in PHP or a way to obtain similar results as the described code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find jasypt digest implementation in PHP here: https://github.com/kevwis/Phpsypt

Comment: Is this library stil available? The GitHub page no longer exists. Maybe do you have a copy of it?

Comment: Same here. A copy would be great.